# Which data structure to use for storage of matrix pairs?

Tags: java, opencv, data-structures, mat

I need a container for 2 different-sized matrices.

Something like this:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;


List<Mat, Mat> listOfMats = new ArrayList<Mat, Mat>();
```

Clearly I can not use the `ArrayList` because of the number of parameters.

Additional information:The both parameters quantity is equal. Each pair of matrices depends on eachother.
Which Data structure would you use here, if you would want to stay efficient. If I would need to make a decision between storage space and run time. I would prefer the first.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your description is not sufficient. What do you mean with "The both parameters quantity is equal.". What does the fact "Each pair of matrices depends on eachother." influence the strcuture?

Comment: Is this a 2 dimensional array of an n-dimnsional matrix? Mat seems to be a dense array. And you want to build pairs of them? dense or non dense. that is the main question,. That depends on the data. It's impossible to answer, if no knwoledge about the distribution of the outer 2d array is given.

Comment: 2 Matrices always belongs to eachother. Which means you don't necessarily need a List as a value. Yes, it is a 2 dimensional array of an n-dimensional matrices. And I'm not quiet sure what you mean by dense here.

Comment: dense matrix vs. sparse matrix. A dense 2d array is one where each possible combination is used. like a chess board, a sparse array is one where most combinations are not used, e.g coordinates of cities. desne arrays are stored using an 2d array like int[][].  Sparse arrays using (linked) lists of variable size.

Comment: Let's say it is near to a sparfe matrix. It is like a diagonal on the chess board then..Non other combination is relevant

Comment: There are so many things to consider: how many elements in the outer 2d array? 100 or 100.000. How do you want to find the correct 2d index? What is you search key? A (matA, matB) query object?

Comment: A diagonal is a one dimensional thing. so I would use an Pair[]. An array of Pairs, where each Pair holds an MatA, and an MatB

Comment: Elements count [200...10000]. Index is irrelevant. Need only an iterator. Pair[] sounds actually what i'm looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pair element in Java. so write one yourself:

```
public class MatrixPair {
   public Mat mat1;
   public Mat mat2;
   public MatrixPair(mat1, mat2) {
     this.mat1 = mat1;
     this.mat2 = mat2; 
   }
}
```

Now store in one array or ArrayList:

```
List<MatPairs> matPairs = new ArrayList<MatPair>();
```

Comment: This is awesome!Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Two dimensional arrays (lists) are usually coded as follows.

```
List<Mat, List<Mat>> listOfMat = new ArrayList<Mat, List<Mat>>();
```

If you very often have the case that the inner list has only one entry,
you can store the Mat directly, but you have to check each time which type
the object is:

```
List<Mat, Object> listOfMat = new ArrayList<Mat, Object>();
```

In one case Object is an List in another case it is just Mat. You can check with

```
   if (obj instanceof Mat) {
       // it i sdirectly a Mat
    } else {
       // it is an List<Mat>
    }
```

Comment: Even if the inner list have only one entry?

Comment: You always have the case that the inner list has only one entry. That's why they are pairs

Comment: Yes and this inner one element is an List. read about 2d arrays in java first. That is totally different to C or C++. An 2d array in java is an 1d array of objects. where each object itself is an array.